# How do you get RabbitMQ queue size from c# client?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I need to set an upper limit on how many messages can be in a queue. So obviously I need to know how many items are in a queue. How do you check the number of messages in a RabbitMQ queue from the c# client without hitting the management API or using QueueDeclarePassive?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, but it has to be [an actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not just an intro to your answer. Read the “Help others” section of the link.

Comment: Help others reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is an example of the message count function on the IModel object. You do not need to use QueueDeclarePassive or make rest request to the management plugin. There is a function right there where it should be.

```
public uint GetMessageCount(string queueName)
{
    using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        return channel.MessageCount(queueName);
    }
}
```

For documentation:
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/api/RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#RabbitMQ_Client_IModel_MessageCount_System_String_